# How to add "Add to VLC playlist" to the right click menu of Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, vlc, media

### The Problem

While you are playing any song or other media file on VLC and open another such file, then another instance of VLC opens. *(You aren't going to hear and understand anything until you are a robot)*

### What I Want

I what to add a "Add to VLC Playlist" to the right click menu of Nautilus as similar in Windows.

Comment: http://blog.revathskumar.com/2011/11/vlc-add-to-playlist-option-in-context.html - this link has a proper answer to this question.

Answer (score 16):

It can be fixed in VLC preferences:

- Open VLC preferences by going to tools menu

[image]

- In preferences, Enable `"Allow only one instance"` and `"Enqueue files in one instance mode"` like shown below:

[image]

- Click save. That's it!

From now on when you open files with VLC they will be enqueued in your playlist.

Comment: The original question was about how to "add **Add to VLC Playlist** to the **right click menu** of Nautilus". This is not answered, yet. I, too, would like to know how that can be done. I'm not a fan of *forcing* "only one instance". Any takers?

Comment: also check http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/17697/ where a work-around is suggested using nautilus-actions (a config. tool), but I'm not that fond of that make-shift solution...

Comment: This answer is good, but it is more a workaround than a real solution. Is there some (easy) way to add the enqueue option to the right click menu?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty Check out https://askubuntu.com/a/857244/114030

Comment: This doesn't guarantee adding multiple files in the playlist in the right order.

Answer (score 6):

## You can do that using nautilus-action-Configuration-Tool

1. Install the tool using using

   ```
   sudo apt-get install nautilus-action
   ```
2. After that close all the open nautilus instances

   ```
   nautilus -q
   ```
3. Open nautilus-action-Configuration-Tool.
4. Then click on add new action button and name your action.
5. Click the Command tab and enter the command

   ```
   vlc --one-instance
   ```

   You should also enter the appropriate parameter into the Parameters box — you can click the Legend button to see a list of parameters you can use.

   In our case, we want the `%f` parameter to feed filename or better `%B` if we may have spaces in it.We can also view all the detailes about the parameters by clicking on the Legend button.

   *Nautilus-Actions shows you a preview of the command it will run, so you’ll know you’re on the right track.*

Comment: What could you do if filename has space in it?! you should use %B not %f

Comment: Yes @Maythux if the filename has space you should use %B my bad. Also you can check clicking  the legend Button

Comment: This package is no longer available.

Answer (score 5):

#### First Method:

Create a new script called `add-to-vlc` inside the directory `~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts`

Add this to the file:

```
#!/bin/bash
for File in "$@"
do
if [ -d "$File" ]; then
zenity --error --text="'$File' is a directory."
exit
fi
done
vlc --one-instance "$File"
```

Give permissions to the file:

```
chmod +x add-to-vlc
```

Now restart nautilus:

```
nautilus -q
```

Now you can use it just right click on a file then go to scripts entry and choose `add-to-vlc`

---

#### Second Method:

Install nautilus actions:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-actions
```

Restart Nautilus:

```
nautilus -q
```

Launch the Nautilus-Actions Configuration Tool from  Dash:

[image]

In the Action Tab Enter the name you want to save:

[image]

In the command tab add the command as below in the picture(path:/usr/bin/vlc and Parameters: --one-instance %B)

[image]

Now save and exit, now whenever you right click on a file you can go to Nautlus Actions and choose `Add to vlc`:

[image]

Comment: Additional option would be `--playlist-enqueue` and for those using multiple instances `--no-playlist-autostart`

Answer (score 0):

Solution using **no other application/tool**: (For `Nautilus 3`)

1. Create a file `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/Add to VLC playlist` with following content in it:

   ```
   #! /bin/bash  
   echo -n "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS" | xargs -d '\n' vlc --one-instance --playlist-enqueue
   ```

   Command to create the required file:

   ```
   echo -e "#! /bin/bash \necho -n \"\$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS\" | xargs -d '\\\n' vlc --one-instance --playlist-enqueue" > ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/"Add to VLC playlist"
   ```
2. Make it executable:

   ```
   chmod u+x ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/"Add to VLC playlist"
   ```

Done!

- Now right click on any media file(s) and select `Add to VLC Playlist` from `Scripts` submenu.
- **Works for directories** too!
  Just include the intended directory or directories (containing audio/video media) in the selection.

---

For `Naultilus 2`
Change `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/"Add to VLC playlist"` to `~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts/"Add to VLC playlist"`