# How do I add convert wav into flac to the context menu?

Tags: sound, plugins, compression

I would like to right click on an wav-audio file in Nautilus or Dolphin and convert it to a FLAC-audio file that way with the highest possible loss less compression.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flac](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/flac/) tool. To install it from [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) you can use the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install flac
```

After the installation, you can convert `.wav` files info `.flac` files as follow (compression level varies from 0 to 8 - 8 being the best):

```
flac -8 source.wav destination.flac
```

Now you have to put the above command in a small bash script, then see, for example, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/346703/147044) to know how to add it in the right click context menu in Nautilus.