# VLC Opens Multiple Instances

Tags: nautilus, 17.10, vlc

When I try to open multiple files with **"Open with VLC media player"** from Nautilus, it opens multiple vlc instances. This didn't happen in earlier ubuntu releases.

I have already set "Use only one instance" from VLC Preferences but, nothing is really working yet.

Is there any setting in Nautilus/VLC which can help me to solve this problem?

Comment: This problem does not happen with mpv Media Player.

Comment: There is a script you can use to solve this issue. I think this is a duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/346285/is-it-possible-to-add-an-option-to-the-context-menu-in-nautilus-to-open-media-in?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to add an option to the context menu in nautilus to open media in an existing VLC instance?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346285/is-it-possible-to-add-an-option-to-the-context-menu-in-nautilus-to-open-media-in)